# Confusing socket.io behavior when .emit() is delayed

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, socket.io

There's some confusing socket / async behavior that I could really use some help understanding.

Here is my (contrived) server code:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3003);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile("index.html");
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});

var room = "random";
var room2 = "another_room";

function make_socket_emit(socket, msg, timeout) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    socket.emit("message", msg);      
  }, timeout);
}

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.join(room);

  make_socket_emit(io.sockets.in(room2), "Ni!", 500);

  make_socket_emit(io.sockets.in(room), "I have been imprisoned by my father, who wishes me to marry against my will.  Please, please, please come and rescue me.", 500);
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test Instantiation Delay and Room Issue</title>
      <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>

</body>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3003');

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connected');

    socket.on("message", function(msg) {
      console.log("Message for you, sir!:", msg);
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

I'd expect only the 'room' message to be sent, but both are sent.

If you switch the order of the 'make_socket_emit' calls, only the message to room2 is received, on my machine.

Many thanks,